# javascript replacechild not working

Tags: javascript

I know this is an easy concept, but I just can't seem to get it working. Any ideas why? Here is my code:

```
var oldChild = document.getElementById("sbX1");
var newChild = document.createElement("div");
newChild.id= "sbYY1";
oldChild.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling `replaceChild()` on `oldchild`, when you ought to be calling it on the parent node of `oldchild`

```
var oldChild = document.getElementById("sbX1");
var newChild = document.createElement("div");
newChild.id= "sbYY1";

// Replace oldchild on the parent node
// You can reference the child's parent via .parentNode
// or retrieve it directly with document.getElementById('theparentId')
oldchild.parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);
```